# Do You Use A Specific Set Of Questions For Developing Your Character

Tags: plot, characters, character-development

So what do you ask them? Do you have a questionnaire?

Comment: We avoid poll-style "Do You Use..." questions; see e.g. [here](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75168/should-polls-be-maintained-as-community-wiki-questions-or-should-they-be-closed). In a nutshell, they really don't work as Q&A - they encourage lots of people to write their own answer ("No, I don't!"), and no one answer is better or worse than another.

Answer (score 2):

Some people do. I don't. I prefer to discover who my characters are by just writing them. I'll put them in scene after scene with each other and see what happens. Sometimes the unexpected happens.

This requires a lot of exploratory writing that might not make it into the final draft, but I find that this technique creates characters that are more natural, yet are surprising. I've tried questionnaires, but they're not as fun as writing scenes and they make you decide things rather than just letting characters reveal themselves to you.

Comment: I usually start with the first sentence and trust in God for the second. However, I often get stuck with the plot somewhere in the middle. As an attempt to avoid it I have now tumbled into planning. But I want to do it in an organized way - hence these questions.

Comment: It's a great question. And I'm sure some planners will have great answers for you. I'm an explorer, though, and I usually find plots as I write these scenes. "Oh, she just slapped a guy! What happens next? What happened before?" (So I guess I'm not really answering your question.)

Comment: The reason I am struggling is that I am working on several books… and the heap is getting bigger every month, but I simply have trouble finishing them, because I get a little disappointed around the middle. Why? Because of all the things in the world I can’t create conflict. Having a rather harmonious personality, I can’t “kill my darlings” as Steven King proposes, as a writing approach.

Comment: @LadyFickle *"of all the things in the world I can’t create conflict"* Surely your characters *want something*. If in any way anyone else might want something that would hamper those characters' ability to get (or make happen) what they want, including that someone else wants to have it for themselves, there's one conflict right there. Conflict need not mean fighting.

Comment: @MichaelKjörling is right, and I'd add that the conflict could be generated by a little thing happening that requires some action: a flat tire, a run-away dog, a found wallet. FYI, I always considered "killing your darlings" to be the act of editing out those favorite passages, words, characters, etc., that don't support the story. I have trouble doing this as well. I love my title or my opening line and have a terrible time replacing it with something that's better for the story.